# PHP slow than HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a very interesting problem.İn PHP

```
            <? $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_slide order by sira asc");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?=$row['picture']?>"><img class="thumb" src="<?=$row['picture']?>" alt="" /></a>
        <h3><?=$row['baslik']?></h3>
        <p><?=$row['icerik']?></p>
    </li>
 <? } ?>
```

I coding something.Everything is okay.But slide show is very slow.But,

in HTML

```
<li>
        <a href="images/background/bg4.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="images/background/bg4_th.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <h3>GABRIELLA DAVIS</h3>
        <p>Mauris id quam mi, nec dictum mauris. Morbi non eros quis erat facilisis scelerisque at in sapien. Etiam amet.</p>
    </li>


    <li>
        <a href="images/background/bg9.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="images/background/bg9_th.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <h3>EMMA JONES</h3>
        <p>Mauris viverra tincidunt est, a bibendum turpis hendrerit eu. Aenean ac elit dolor. Donec commodo, enim metus.</p>
    </li>
<li>
        <a href="images/background/bg10.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="images/background/bg10_th.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <h3>CLAIRE WILLIAMS</h3>
        <p>Mauris viverra tincidunt est, a bibendum turpis hendrerit eu. Aenean ac elit dolor. Donec commodo, enim metus.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="images/background/bg17.jpg"><img class="thumb" src="images/background/bg17_th.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <h3>MARIA WILSON</h3>
        <p>Mauris viverra tincidunt est, a bibendum turpis hendrerit eu. Aenean ac elit dolor. Donec commodo, enim metus.</p>
    </li>
```

when i use this code,slideshow is very fast.İmages is same.
What is the reason for this?

Comment: What is the resultant markup from your PHP script?

Comment: it is possible that the connection to the DB is slow?

Comment: Plain HTML is always more FAST than PHP. *Always*. So this is not a question but just describes a fact.

Comment: Is the page load time slow, or do you mean that the slideshow operates slowly after the page has loaded? Because that would be a lot stranger.

Comment: @hakra: what's that got to do with how fast the slideshow is?

Comment: If you're referring to the page loading slowly, then it is obvious that it's happening due to database connection and pulling records from the databaSe

Comment: Yes,in PHP database connection taking time but in PHP slideshow is an abnormally slow.

Comment: The slideshow doesn't run in PHP it runs in the browser which doesn't know about PHP. If the generated html is the same as the static html, then what you are saying is impossible. If your database generates huge html, then of course it's slower because the slideshow is bigger

Comment: html is not at all a scripting language and you can not compare html with php. compare your html output came from php code with your static one you will find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The browser has no idea what's the source of your page is. An HTML file or a PHP generated HTML page is all the same to it.

Based on this, the only logical *conclusion* is that the *contents* of the two pages *differ* in some important way. If they were the same, they would behave the same way.

Check the source of the generated page and compare it with your test page, doing diffs and eliminating HTML parts which don't affect the performance. You should be able to locate the problem.

Maybe the PHP generated page contains a lot of items, or extra markup which kills the performance?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has to make a connection to the MySQL server (whether this is local or remote). It must then run the query, wait for the result, parse the returned data and format the output.

Loading the HTML directly will always be faster. There are techniques to help improve speed, but there are many factors involved. The first place to look is probably your hosting platform.

Comment: My hosting platform is localhost...

Comment: It doesn't matter. See the other answers to your question. There are many factors involved. I suggest you look at how n-tier web architecture works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture